# HttpEntity reset after closing and throws java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
  public static String sendRequest(UUICRequest requset) throws
      ClientProtocolException, IOException
  {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requset.toUrl());
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    response.close();
    httpClient.close();
    return EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
  }
```

It throws `java.net.SocketException: socket closed`.

I debugged and ran this program line by line, just found `entity` changed when excuted:

```
    response.close();
    httpClient.close();
```

So I rewrite my code:

```
  public static String sendRequest(UUICRequest requset) throws
      ClientProtocolException, IOException
  {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requset.toUrl());
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String ret = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");//+
    response.close();
    httpClient.close();
    return ret;//M
  }
```

This code works as expected and successfully ends.

My question is, why `httpclient` will reset `entity` after closing `response` and `httpClient`?

Comment: Thank you for this question. I had the exactly same bug, and this helped me to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, why httpclient will reset entity after closing response and httpClient?

Streaming HTTP entities (such as those returned with an `HttpResponse`) are attached to the underlying connection in order to be able to stream data out without any intermediate buffering. Closing `HttpResponse` before response content has been fully consumed causes the underlying connection to get reset.

Comment: Is there any elegant way for @Sayakiss to solve the problem?